# Java program failing to map Native memory allocation

Tags: java, heap-memory

Java program failing to allocate Native memory even after enough RAM is available.

The program crashes repeatedly after failing with os_commit exceptions.

Any recommendation to update to tune Java Heap etc.

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=35462, tid=140393234093824
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/hdp/share/hst/activity-analyzer/core or core.35462
#
```

As per the logs you can see that there is enough memory available

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 264266920k(135968600k free), swap 8393468k(8393468k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_65-b17), built on Oct  6 2015 17:16:12 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Tue Feb  5 05:54:26 2019
elapsed time: 2928 seconds (0d 0h 48m 48s)
```

Resource Utilization

```
# free -mg
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           252        134        117          0          0         25
-/+ buffers/cache:        108        143
Swap:            8          0          8
```

JMap Output

```
# jmap -heap 2820
Attaching to process ID 2820, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.65-b01

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 33 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 33554432000 (32000.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 44564480 (42.5MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 11184635904 (10666.5MB)
   OldSize                  = 89653248 (85.5MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 9320267776 (8888.5MB)
   used     = 7558977896 (7208.803077697754MB)
   free     = 1761289880 (1679.696922302246MB)
   81.10258286209995% used
From Space:
   capacity = 262668288 (250.5MB)
   used     = 242645032 (231.40433502197266MB)
   free     = 20023256 (19.095664978027344MB)
   92.37698004869168% used
To Space:
   capacity = 346030080 (330.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 346030080 (330.0MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 715653120 (682.5MB)
   used     = 395523640 (377.2007369995117MB)
   free     = 320129480 (305.2992630004883MB)
   55.267507252675706% used

22626 interned Strings occupying 2218928 bytes.
```

Java Version

```
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Redhat Release

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Comment: Do you use any jvm parameters? What OS and architecture are you using?

Comment: Which JRE are you using?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Does anybody know why it says "In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit" but then when specifying VM version indicates that you are using a 64-bit Server ("Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server")? These messages seem contradictory. I am experiencing the same issue, with the same exact amount of bytes (12288) using Java 8.0_181-b13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are possibly impacted by [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187709)

As per the post's suggested workarounds :

> There are 2 possible workaround here
>
> 1. Disable compressed Oops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops) with slight performance penalty. This will instruct JVM to run without the
>    Compressed Oops feature and it would not try to fit the Java Heap in
>    the first 4GB of heap
> 2. Keep the CompressedOops and set the base of the Java Heap with the JVM option -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=n to specify the address where the
>    Java Heap should start from set it to a higher address so that there
>    is enough room available for the native mallocs

Comment: Thanks for this. The bug is for version 8u131. The OP is using a different version. Can this still be relevant? (I am also using a different version).